# Finding K value?

Tags: solution-verification, geometric-progressions

Suppose that a geometric progression (GP) $1, q, q^{2}, \ldots$ (where $|q|<1)$ is to be constructed such that every term of this GP is a constant multiple (say $k$ ) of sum of all the subsequent terms. For what values of $k$ is this problem solvable?

**My Approach:**
$1+q+q^{2}+\cdots \cdot \alpha$

$q=k\left(q^{2}+q^{3}+\cdots\right)$

$q=k \times \frac{q^{2}}{(1-q)}$

$k q=1-q$

$S_{0} \quad k=\frac{1-q}{q}$

*Am I Correct?*

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it seems correct. But I think it is better to use a general exponent $n$. Let $$s_n=\sum_{i=0}^{n}q^i=\frac{1-q^{n+1}}{1-q}.$$
And let $S=\lim_{n \to \infty}s_n=\frac{1}{1-q}$.
Now, we require that $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$, $$q^n=k(q^{n+1}+q^{n+2}+...)$$ 
In other terms,
$$k=\frac{q^n}{S-s_n}$$
$$k=\frac{q^n}{\frac{1}{1-q}-\frac{1-q^{n+1}}{1-q}}$$
$$...k=\frac{1-q}{q}.$$

Comment: check your calculation,how q^n going to the denominator in the 2nd step

Comment: moreover take a value q (say 1/3),then k = 1/2, it would not support

Comment: @RANCHO Apologies! How silly of me. I'll correct it.

Comment: it's okay! approach is nice though